# Grouped boxplot in R - simplest way

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have been struggling with creating a very simple grouped boxplot. My data looks as follows

```
> data
     Wörter Sätze Text
P.01   0.15  0.24 0.34
P.02   0.10  0.15 0.08
P.03   0.05  0.18 0.16
P.04   0.55  0.60 0.44
P.05   0.00  0.06 0.26
P.06   0.20  0.65 0.68
P.07   0.15  0.31 0.47
P.08   0.35  0.87 0.69
P.09   0.35  0.75 0.76
N.01   0.40  0.78 0.59
N.02   0.55  0.95 0.76
N.03   0.65  0.96 0.83
N.04   0.60  0.90 0.77
N.05   0.50  0.95 0.82
```

If I simply execute boxplot(data) I obtain almost what I want. One plot with three boxes, each for one of the variables in my data.

[Boxplot, almost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o77QG.png)

What I want is to separate these into two boxes per variable (one for the P-indexed, one for the N-indexed observations) for a total of six plots each.

I began by introducing a new variable

```
data$Gruppe <- c(rep("P",9), rep("N",5)) 

> data
     Wörter Sätze Text Gruppe
P.01   0.15  0.24 0.34      P
P.02   0.10  0.15 0.08      P
P.03   0.05  0.18 0.16      P
P.04   0.55  0.60 0.44      P
P.05   0.00  0.06 0.26      P
P.06   0.20  0.65 0.68      P
P.07   0.15  0.31 0.47      P
P.08   0.35  0.87 0.69      P
P.09   0.35  0.75 0.76      P
N.01   0.40  0.78 0.59      N
N.02   0.55  0.95 0.76      N
N.03   0.65  0.96 0.83      N
N.04   0.60  0.90 0.77      N
N.05   0.50  0.95 0.82      N
```

Now that the data contains a non-numerical variable I cannot simply execute the boxplot() function as before. What would be a minimal alteration to make here to obtain the six plots that I want? (colour coding for the two groups would be nice)

I have encountered some solutions to a grouped boxplot, however the data from which others start tends to be organised differently than my (very simple) one.

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use [`tidyr::pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) to reshape your data from a wide format to a long format.

Comment: hi @teunbrand, I don't really see how that would help. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @teunbrand already mentioned in the comments you could use `pivot_longer` to make your data in a longer format by Gruppe. You could use `fill` to make  for each variable two boxplot in total 6 like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data$Gruppe <- c(rep("P",9), rep("N",5)) 

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Gruppe) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Gruppe)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Data used:

```
data <- read.table(text = "     Wörter Sätze Text
P.01   0.15  0.24 0.34
P.02   0.10  0.15 0.08
P.03   0.05  0.18 0.16
P.04   0.55  0.60 0.44
P.05   0.00  0.06 0.26
P.06   0.20  0.65 0.68
P.07   0.15  0.31 0.47
P.08   0.35  0.87 0.69
P.09   0.35  0.75 0.76
N.01   0.40  0.78 0.59
N.02   0.55  0.95 0.76
N.03   0.65  0.96 0.83
N.04   0.60  0.90 0.77
N.05   0.50  0.95 0.82", header = TRUE)
```